# くれれば and くれば difference

Tags: conjugations

What's the difference in using くれば and くれれば? For example:

> 教えて**くれば**感謝
> 教えて**くれれば**感謝

They both mean exactly the same thing. I am assuming くれれば is really くれる conjugated to it's if form, but isn't くれば also the same?

Comment: They both mean the same thing according to who?

Comment: くれれば is a form of くれる, and くれば is a form of くる. They are two different verbs with very different meanings.

Comment: 「教えてくれば感謝。」ってどういう意味かわかりません。それ見たら普通は「教えてくれれば感謝」の書き間違いだろうと思うと思います。

Comment: @Chocolate　聞いたことないっすがくればとくれればはくれるから作った言葉で意味は同じだと思ったから

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking at two different verbs/grammars (くる and くれる), so even though the end result appears to be the same with some translation tools (*cough cough* google), there is actually a difference between the two.

Let's start with the first sentence.

> 教えてくれば感謝

The grammar being used here is the ～て + くる grammar.  According to 'A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar', くる functions as "an auxiliary verb which indicates the beginning of some process or continuation of some action up to a current point of time."

This means that 教えてくる can be translated as `begin to teach.`

～ば is a grammar formation for 'if.'  As an irregular verb, くる joins with ば in a way unique from other verbs.  In this case, くる + ば = くれば.  We'll have more on the conjugation here later, but let's get on with what this means.

This means that 教えてくれば means `if (implied person) begin(s) to teach.`

Therefore the first case would be something like: `(I'd) be grateful if (you) started to teach.`  Depending on context, who the speaker is talking to, and a number of other factors, the person doing the teaching and the person doing the thanking will change.  However, that's the gist of what's happening.

---

> 教えてくれれば感謝

The grammar being used here is ～て + くれる.  According to 'A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar' we can understand this grammar as "someone does something as a favor to the first person or to someone with whom the speaker empathizes."

This means that 教えてくれる can be translated as `teach as a favor to me.`

Once again, we have the ～ば form of 'if.'  Using [this guide for conjugation rules,](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%B0-ba-conditional-form-meaning/) we can see that くれる + ば = くれれば.  The conjugation here is distinct from the previous example.

This means that 教えてくれれば means `if (implied person) teach(es) as a favor to me.`

Therefore, this second case would be translated something like: `(I'd) be grateful if (you) teach as a favor to me.`  Again the people involved and meaning of the sentence will change with context, who is speaking, and other factors.

---

If you oversimplify these translations to make them sound more natural in English, you can run into cases where the translations of both phrases are the same (like you see in google translate).  Be careful to not trust translation tools implicitly, as sometimes meaning is lost in translation, especially if you don't pay attention to the grammar/words at play in the phrases you are translating.

---

#### Note:

This assumes that you are using [教える](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B) as `to teach.`  The same principles also apply if you use the meaning `to tell/inform.`